# PHP CLI multiple background processes limitation

Tags: php, linux, perl, parallel-processing

Server Information:

- CentOS 6.5
- 12GB RAM
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 @ 6 CPU x 2.20GHz
- PHP CLI 5.5.7

I am currently trying to use Perl to fire off 1000 PHP CLI processes in parallel. This however takes **9.9 seconds vs 2.3 seconds** for the equivalent Perl script. When I test using the Perl script `/opt/test.pl`, all 1000 processes are launched in parallel (`ps -eLf | grep -ic 'test.pl'`).  When I test using `/opt/testphp.php`, using `ps -eLf | grep -ic 'testphp.php'`, I see a count of 250, then it rises to 580 and then it drops to 0 (the script is executed 1000 times, just not in parallel).

- Is there a limitation preventing a high number of PHP CLI processes from being launched in parallel?
- Has anyone experienced this issue?

Please let me know if I have left out anything that would help to identify the issue.

Thanks

**Perl launcher script:**

```
use Time::HiRes qw/ time sleep /;

my $command = '';
my $start = time;
my $filename = '/tmp/report.txt';

# open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

for $i(1 .. 1000) {
    # $command = $command . "(perl /opt/test.pl &);"; // takes 2.3 seconds
    $command = $command . "(php -q /opt/testphp.php &);"; // takes 9.9 seconds
}

system($command);

my $end = time;

print 'Total time taken: ', ( $end - $start ) , "\n";
```

**PHP file (testphp.php):**

```
sleep(5);

$time = microtime(true);

file_put_contents('/tmp/report_20140804_php.log', "This is the record: $time\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

**Perl file (test.pl):**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Time::HiRes qw/ time sleep /;

sleep(5);

my $command = '';
my $start = time;
my $filename = '/tmp/report_20140804.log';

open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

print $fh "Successfully saved entry $start\n";

close $fh;
```